# Can't build media in Install4J 7.0.6

Tags: install4j

The build output:

```
Preparing configuration

Creating media file 'macOS Folder':
  Collecting files:
  Compiling launchers:
    Compiling launcher 'jarcomp':
      Generating VM options file vmoptions.txt.
  Creating media file: 

Build failed.

Cause: com.ejt.a.c.g
       Failed to compile script
       ----------
       In Static members:
       1. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *6)
        import com.install4j.api.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       2. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *7)
        import com.install4j.api.beans.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       3. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *8)
        import com.install4j.api.context.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       4. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *9)
        import com.install4j.api.events.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       5. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *10)
        import com.install4j.api.screens.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       6. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *11)
        import com.install4j.api.actions.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       7. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *12)
        import com.install4j.api.formcomponents.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       8. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *13)
        import com.install4j.api.update.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       9. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *14)
        import com.install4j.api.windows.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       In Static members:
       10. ERROR in /private/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/script6949291855714040150.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_0.java (at line *15)
        import com.install4j.api.unix.*;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       The import com.install4j.api cannot be resolved
       ----------
       10 problems (10 errors)

       Classpath: /Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/i4j_nonmod1544375354488858380.jar:/var/folders/pf/m6dkqhld1hl4gwr21t9vtxkc0000gp/T/install4j6393763453946675866_dir/set1/custom:/Applications/install4j.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/pdf-viewer.jar

You can select the "Enable extra verbose output" option to get more information, including a stack trace.
```

[The Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFcyu.png)

Comment: Do you get this with the sample projects as well? Can you prepare a reproducible test case and send it to support@ej-technologies.com?